# Nav Menu: Theme Location not working

Tags: menus, navigation

Why do my created Menus on the WordPress Admin dashboard appear in `customtemplate.php` DESPITE not defining it the correct `'theme_location'`?

It will show in that location EVEN if the created menu in the WordPress Admin dashboard is not set to show in any location.

It only hides if the following if check is tested. Why?

```
if(has_nav_menu('menu-ID1'))
```

**Functions.php**

```
register_nav_menus(
            array(
                'menu-ID1' => __( 'MenuName', 'blabla' ),
            )
        );
```

**customtemplate.php**

```
//Still displays even though the registered menu-ID1 is not used    
wp_nav_menu(['theme_location' => 'randomname']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your menu contains only Pages (posts of the `page` type) on your site?

But nonetheless, with [`wp_nav_menu()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/), if you specify a `theme_location` that doesn't exist or contains no menu (i.e. no menus assigned to that location), then the `fallback_cb` arg (which defaults to [`wp_page_menu()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_page_menu/)) will determine what is displayed.

So if you want the function to display the menu only if it's assigned to the specified theme location, you can do the `has_nav_menu()` check:

```php
if ( has_nav_menu( 'menu-ID1' ) ) {
    wp_nav_menu( 'theme_location=menu-ID1' );
}
```

or set the `fallback_cb` to an empty string:

```php
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'menu-ID1',
    'fallback_cb'    => '',
) );

// or you may pass the function args as a query string:
wp_nav_menu( 'theme_location=menu-ID1&fallback_cb=' );
```

Comment: Excellent. This answers the question, thank you